# display text if cart items = 0

Tags: php, joomla, cart

i'm having issues with the code i wrote up below. basically, when there are x items in the cart, it echoes the text "You have x item(s) in the cart". However, when there are no items, it should echo "You don't have any items in the cart" but instead echoes nothing. What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php 
    $array = unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']); 
    foreach($array->products as $product){
        $amount = $product->amount;
        if ($amount != 0){ echo "You have $amount item(s) in the cart."; } 
        else { echo "You don't have any items in the cart."; } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does it come in the loop when there are no products?

Comment: Are you sure that `$product->amount` is set for no items and you don't have any errors in log?

Comment: when there are no products nothing is echoed at all

Comment: if `$array->products` is empty (no items) the loop is never entered, and no messages will be shown

Comment: how can this be fixed then? i'm sorry i'm a complete novice at php

Comment: btw the code worked beautifully. thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the code does not come in the for each loop.

```
<?php 
    $array = unserialize($_SESSION['__vm']['vmcart']); 
    if (count($array->products) > 0) {
      foreach($array->products as $product){
          $amount = $product->amount;
          echo "You have $amount item(s) in the cart."; 
          /* Do other thinks here. */
      }
    } else { 
     echo "You don't have any items in the cart."; 
    } 
?>
```

I'm not sure why you wanne use a loop btw.

Comment: Maybe he has two or more products of one type in the cart that's why `amount` property is introduced.

Comment: i want to loop through all the products

Comment: and for each prodcut you want to show the text `You have X items in the cart` ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it must be a sum of amounts of all products in a single output.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your foreach and use this

```
if($size=sizeof($array->products))
echo "You have ".$size." item(s) in the cart.";
else
echo "You don't have any items in the cart.";
```